# Many to One Relation on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

You think a company.The company have employee on Users table.Managers must be on Users table.

Example:

```
Users Table : John Watson userID=1 managerId=2(manager id have userID value)
              Emilia Clarke userID=2 managerID=null(Because this user is a Manager)
```

What do you think how i do it? managerID row Many to One relation with Users table(Despite having the same table)

**Emilia Clark manager of John Watson (because john's managerID, emilia's userID**

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please include a sample data table (with records) and another table showing the desired output.  Please refer to what research you have undertaken, with particular mention going to anything that was especially useful.  Please show us what code you have tried (if any) and the full text of any error messages the code is producing.  For more information on how to ask a Question, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the userId and add a boolean isManager which takes the value true if the user is a manager, false otherwhise.

Comment: Sorry i didn't tell you.I meant Emilia Clark manager of John Watson (because john's managerID, emilia's userID

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of employees and the details of their managers, please try the following...

```
SELECT employee.userID,
       employee.userName,
       manager.userID,
       manager.userName
FROM Users AS employee
JOIN Users AS manager ON employee.managerID = manager.userID
ORDER BY employee.userName,
         employee.userID;
```

To get a list of managers and their Employees, please try the following...

```
SELECT manager.userID,
       manager.userName
       employee.userID,
       employee.userName,
FROM Users AS manager
JOIN Users AS employee ON manager.userID = employee.managerID
ORDER BY manager.userName,
         manager.userID,
         employee.userName,
         employee.userID;
```

(Explanation to follow...)

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can map as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = ...)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private Set<User> employees;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id"
    private User manager;
}
```